# Is there a way to detect if a Flutter App is on a Desktop Mode from an Android Device like Samsung DeX?

Tags: android, flutter, samsung-dex

I need to optimize a Flutter App for Samsung DeX, without changing the behavior of the app, when is running on a normal Smartphone or Tablet. So my question is, is it possible to detect if an App is running in a Desktop Mode from an Android Device like Samsung DeX?

I already tried using the width of the screen, but this didn't work out, because of the screens of some tablets.

Answer (score 0):

It might help, you can try using the 'Platform.isDesktop' property to check if the app is running in desktop mode.

```html
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isDesktop) {
  // Running in desktop mode
} else {
  // Running in mobile mode
}
```

This can be useful for adapting your app's behavior to different screen sizes and input methods.

Comment: My Platform class from dart:io only contains the following detections:

Platform.isAndroid
Platform.isFuchsia
Platform.isIOS
Platform.isLinux
Platform.isMacOS
Platform.isWindows

Comment: In that case, you can try the Window.physicalSize property to detect if the app is running in desktop mode.

if (Window.physicalSize.width > 1000) {
  // Running in desktop mode
} else {
  // Running in mobile mode
}

Answer (score 0):

You need use native Android api. In Java/Kotlin, call `UiModeManager.getCurrentModeType()`([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager#getCurrentModeType())). The desktop mode have value `2`, which is `UI_MODE_TYPE_DESK`([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#UI_MODE_TYPE_DESK))

Update: I found a plugin for this: [flutter_ui_mode_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ui_mode_manager).
You can use `FlutterUiModeManager.getDeviceUiMode` and look for `UiMode.UI_MODE_TYPE_DESK`